# Wrapping words in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've come across an issue which seems to be present in only Firefox. I've been trying to wrap the words correctly, however they seem to be cutting short. I've tried numerous solutions I've found to no avail.

My current custom CSS stands as

```
h2,  .ish-h2{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px !important;
word-break: keep-all !important;
-moz-hyphens: auto !important;
}
```

I've tried adding `white-space: pre-wrap !important;` but that doesn't fix the words cutting off.

My goal is to have it so that the words wrap, but do not cut off. I'm trying to make it responsive, as well.

[image: Word Wrap Problem]

Comment: Can you toss your html and css into a jsfiddle

Comment: I can't seem to reciprocate the issue on JSFiddle, could be that the thing is automatically wrapping: http://jsfiddle.net/7o32wpe8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Solution Found.

The error was that the CSS property was conflicting with another styles.css that contained:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

By removing that, It fixed the words breaking up like that.